# Confusion Matrix three classes python

Tags: python, confusion-matrix

I want to calculate:

```
True_Positive, False_Positive, False_Negative, True_Negative
```

for three categories. I used to have two classes `Cat` `Dog` and this is the way I used to calculate my confusion_matrix

> y_pred has either a cat or dog
>
> y_true has either a cat or dog

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_matrix_output =confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred) 
True_Positive = confusion_matrix_output[0][0]
False_Positive = confusion_matrix_output[0][1]
False_Negative = confusion_matrix_output[1][0]
True_Negative = confusion_matrix_output[1][1]
```

---

Now I have three classes 'Cat' 'Dog' 'rabbit'

```
Y_pred has Cat Dog rabbit
y_true has Cat Dog rabbit
```

How to calculate `True_Positive, False_Positive, False_Negative, True_Negative`?

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/51301/36229

Answer (score 13):

Multi-class Confusion Matrix is very well established in literature; you could find it easily on your own. Anyhow, [Scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) can do it easily like:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

y_true = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Rabbit', 'Cat', 'Cat', 'Rabbit']
y_pred = ['Dog', 'Dog', 'Rabbit', 'Dog', 'Dog', 'Rabbit']

classes=['Cat', 'Dog', 'Rabbit']

confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=['Cat', 'Dog', 'Rabbit'])

array([[0, 3, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 2]])
```

You can even plot it nicely using [the below function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py):

```
def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes,
                          normalize=False,
                          title='Confusion matrix',
                          cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    """
    This function prints and plots the confusion matrix.
    Normalization can be applied by setting `normalize=True`.
    """
    import itertools
    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        print("Normalized confusion matrix")
    else:
        print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')

    print(cm)

    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)

    fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
    thresh = cm.max() / 2.
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
        plt.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt),
                 horizontalalignment="center",
                 color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
    plt.tight_layout()
```

like this:

```
cnf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred,labels=['Cat', 'Dog', 'Rabbit'])
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)

# Plot non-normalized confusion matrix
plt.figure()
plot_confusion_matrix(cnf_matrix, classes=['Cat', 'Dog', 'Rabbit'],
                      title='Confusion matrix, without normalization')
```

[image]

More examples [here](https://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/evaluate/confusion_matrix/) and [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/confusion-matrix-machine-learning/).

Comment: what's the difference between the normal confusion matrix and the multilabel confusion matrix?